# Can adjectives be combined with correlatives (table words)?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, correlatives

For example:

> alia io/iu  -  something/someone else

> io ajn malbona - anything bad

Are these correct? If not, is there another way to say this kind of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> alia iu - something/someone else

Oni diras `iu alia`. La klarigo gramatika troveblas [ĉi tie](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/oa-vortecaj_vortetoj/tabelvortoj_u.html#i-l9i), sed oni povas resumi jene: *"Iu iom similas al individueca aŭ duondifina unu."*

> alia io

Kvankam vi *teorie* povus diri tion tiel (Zamenhof en frua teksto skribis *"kio estas la aldona io, pri kiu ..."*) la kutima ordo estas `io alia`.

> io ajn malbona - anything bad

**Tre ofte `io malbona` sufiĉas**, ĉar `io` jam estas nedifinita. Vi [povus](https://tekstaro.com/?s=61744e8d13711) klopodi emfazi tiun nedefinitecon per `ajn` tamen sed oni tion faras tre malofte.

Pli kutima alternativo por substreki la nedifinitecon per `i-` tabelvorto kaj `ajn` estas la strukturo `iu ajn + adjektivo + substantivo`, ekzemple (el tekstaro.com):

```
iu ajn nacia lingvo
iu ajn scienca malkovro
iu ajn malagrabla sento
```

Comment: @Olivro18, in English you use "any" much more often than "ajn" in Esperanto.  For instance if you translate "I have got eggs" and "I have not got any eggs", the latter does not translate to a phrase with "ajn" in Esperanto. It is like Eduardo says, "ajn" is to really underline the indefiniteness.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for explaining! I didn’t realize that! :-)